# jssor gallery - a couple of questions

Tags: jssor

I have a couple of questions about the jssor gallery.

Firstly, is there somewhere that will provide the code for every transition available for it? I have set my slideshow to "random" and I want as many possible transitions as possible because then the chances of the same one appearing at a similar time is fairly small. I have been here: http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html and copied a few, but it's fairly long and tedious and I was hoping there would be an easier way?

Secondly, I have it in a separate PHP file from where it appears on my homepage, and because of this when I include it in my homepage, the style and script tags are not in the head where they belong. If it's possible, would it be able to separate the CSS into different style sheets and include them in my homepage and the same for the JQuery? I have tried this but it doesn't work. It's as if there is no CSS at all.

Thirdly, I run it through the w3 validator and it's bringing up over 200 errors on my homepage - I.E.

there is no attribute "u"

Again:

" t2="" d=-1800 du=3800 class="captionBlack" style="pos…

there is no attribute "t"

Any way to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

re: transitions

As there are infinite transitions, you need to copy transition codes that you need.

re: move css

For now, you can move inline styles to css file or css block (with class name `<div class="yourclassname" ...`). And I will optimize this feature for next version.

re: custom attributes "u" and "t"

You can use "data-u" instead of "u".

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Would I be able to add any of the jquery into a separate file that is the config for the slides or not?

Comment: Just wondering whether there's been any advancement on this yet? I'm updating my site at the moment and on checking I can still see at Github that the "u" attributes still exist.