# Lazy loading (data-src2) Jssor Slider doesn't validate against w3 standards

Tags: html, w3c, w3c-validation, jssor

> **Update:** In short, my problem is neither with `data-u`, `data-src2` nor with any of `data-*` attributes themselves. My problem is that using `data-src2` attribute leaves my img tag without a **`src`** attribute which is a problem for [w3c](/questions/tagged/w3c).

Of course it won't :) But I wonder if there is a workaround?

For the record, yes I have gone through [jssor](/questions/tagged/jssor) questions mentioning about [w3c](/questions/tagged/w3c) validation:

- [JSSOR not w3 valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279163/jssor-not-w3-valid)
- [jssor gallery - a couple of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200141/jssor-gallery-a-couple-of-questions)
- [“u” property within an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382581/u-property-within-an-element)

I am using [jssor slider](http://www.jssor.com/) from [jssor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2110412/jssor) (*I must thank him for the great work and his fast answers about the slider*) with lazy loading images via `data-src2` as documented in [the reference page](http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html) of jssor which w3 validator apparently complains about the images not having `src` attribute:

> **Element img is missing required attribute src.**

I believe [pass html Validation (against w3c standards)](http://www.jssor.com/development/pass-html-validation.html) page should contain one extra list item about validating lazy loading images. So, is there a way to work this around or should we wait for the next version as the author stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23219129/306921) as:

> I will enhance custom attribute handling for next version. at that
>   time, you can use "data-u" instead of "u"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom attribute like `data-u` is w3c standard of html5. Please try html5 validation.

To make an image lazy loading, the `src` attribute shouldn't be specified.
The html5 validation will raise an error for image with no `src` attribute.
Actually, it doesn't matter. I'd say there is no way to fix it at the moment.

Comment: yes `data-u` is valid and so is `data-src2`. My problem is when I use `data-src2` (to lazy load) `img` tag then doesn't have a `src` attribute which w3c validator comlains about by saying:  _"Element img is missing required attribute src."_

Comment: I believe my question is not well received yet. My problem is not with data-* attributes. My problem is that using data-src2 attribute leaves my img tag without a src attribute and this is a problem for w3c.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll mark as anwer in case you update your answer with the above comment.

Answer (score 3):

The solution here is to set a `src` that points to an image that won't be noticed until the lazy-loaded image kicks in. A typical 1x1 pixel transparent `.png` or `.gif` will do the trick.

Once you have made the `pixel.png` image available somewhere on your server, you can do:

```
<img class="lazy" src="/img/pixel.png" data-src="/img/image-to-load.jpg" alt="" title=""/>
```

Your lazy-loading will continue to work and you'll get your `html` validation back.

Comment: Note that I'm not familiar with Jssor Slider, but use this solution with my generic lazy-loader without problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried using an empty `src` attribute beforehands, after reading your answer I have tried a small picture (the loader image I use for the slider) but it seems like `src` attribute is dominating `data-src2` attribute. Jssor doesn't replace the above mentioned `src` atribute with `data-src2` for the time being... +1 for the idea though.

Comment: @jssor this thanks to @Wallace Sidhée 's idea seems to contain hope :) would it mean that we would expect something like jssor replaces `src` with `data-src2` attribute wherever it sees them both exits, in near future?